# React Components interactivity in different DOM nodes (paralel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation like similar:

```
<div className="container">
    <div>
        <PermissionsTable \>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Save Changes" readOnly />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the button to control an action of PermissionsTable, however since they are not on the same DOM level, but they are on paralel, I am not able to easily control the button based on PermissionsTable data.

For example, I need to disable the Save Changes button if the permissions table is not dirty, and I should be able to control each PermissionsTable dirty state by clicking on Save Changes button (which means that once saved, all rows should be non-dirty anymore).

This would be very easy if `PermissionsTable` was a parent of the Save Changes button, however this is not possible since that's not how I can build the DOM given my product specs.

I also thought about adding some sort of `PermissionsTableContext` around the container so that I could interact with both elements under the same scope, however I am not sure if that's the right React-approach (see below).

```
<PermissionsTableArea>
    <div className="container">
        <div>
            <PermissionsTable \>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Save Changes" readOnly />
        </div>
    </div>
</PermissionsTableArea>
```

I tried to achieve this by using references, which partially works however I do not have full control on the whole system, since it becomes extremely cluttered with all sorts of function references coming from a child component.

Comment: A common technique for when sibling components need to interact with each other is to [lift the state up to the first common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). That might be worth looking into.

Comment: The issue by lifting the state up is that if I handle the dirtyness in the first common ancestor, every state refresh will force a re-render of EVERY SINGLE children, which drastically affects performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
class PermissionTableArea extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state={
            data
        }
    }

    handleClickButton= () => {
        let data = this.state.data;
        this.setState({data: setNonDirty(data)}
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div>
                    <PermissionsTable data={this.state.data} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input 
                        type="button" 
                        value="Save Changes" 
                        onClick={this.handleClickButton}
                        readOnly={isDirty(this.state.data)} 
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```